# Flutter API : How to post an "int" to a Json file without converting to a String?

Tags: json, flutter, api, rest, dart

```
    Future<DataModel?> submitData(String name, int age) async {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.http("localhost:3000", "users"), body: {
    "name" : name,
    "job"  : age,
  });
  var data = response.body;
  print(data);

  if(response.statusCode == 201){
    String responseString = response.body;
    return dataModelFromJson(responseString);
  }
  else return null!;
}
```

I want to Post the age as an int but couldn't find a way to do that, the only thing i have to do is to convert the age to a String which i don't want to do.
Is there any solution !??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with Dio.

first i added this line to pubspec.yaml  :

```
 dependencies:
  dio: ^4.0.6
```

make sure to import it :

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
```

My final HTTP request  :

```
var dio = Dio(); 
var response = await dio.post('http://localhost:3000/users', data: {
    "name" : name,
    "job"  : age,
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you the `jsonEncode` function from the `dart:convert` library.

```
body: jsonEncode(
  {
    "name": name,
    "job": job,
    "age": age,
  },
```

Make sure to import

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Your final HTTP request will look like this:

```
var response = await http.post(
  Uri.http("localhost:3000", "users"),
  body: jsonEncode({
    "name": name,
    "job": job,
    "age": age,
  }),
);
```

Comment: Thank you, well, when I tried your solution, I had another problem, in my json file only "id" was added, I don't know what the problem is yet, but it might help others. (I fixed the issue with the Dio package which worked perfectly)